# How can I add the run-as header in spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've spent a while searching for this on Google, but it appears that there is no way to add a header through an `ElasticsearchTemplate/Operations` object. I can't find any way to set the `es-security-runas-user` header. Without that, I cannot execute requests on behalf of a user with my REST service. Does anyone know if this is possible with Spring Data Elasticsearch right now? If not, I have to rewrite a lot of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch you are using.

With the current version 3.2 you can use the following configuration bean:

```
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("es-security-runas-user", "some-user");
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() //
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200") //
                .withDefaultHeaders(httpHeaders) //
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

There is no possibility to send headers on individual operations.